# How to get the list of teradata tables from a particular database using SAS?

Tags: sas, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to get the tables using the following proc sql statement:

```
proc sql;
    Select tablename from dbc.tables;
run;
```

I have already defined the teradata and SQL server locations required. The error I get is "File dbc.tables does not exist"

If I run the query in Teradata SQL assistant, it works. Its just that I am unable to do the same using SAS.

Comment: Can't help you with the SAS piece of it, but you should use `dbc.tablesv`, not `dbc.tables`'.  This applies to at least most of the views in dbc.  `tables` will truncate the name columns at 30 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dictionary.tables`

```
proc sql;
    select memname
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = 'YOUR LIBNAME HERE'
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proc datasets lib=<your library reference>;
run;
```

If you don't know your library reference, but you assume the library is assigned, try

```
proc sql;
select * from sasHelp.vlibnames;
quit;
```

If that does not help and you are working in Enterprise Guide, connected to a metaserver, click on `Servers`, your server, `Libraries` and make sure the button to see non-assigned libraries is set.